# Creating JSON response

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

i'm really newbie at in swift..

i would post a json respons to a webservice..

with this code:

```
let parameters = [
    "id": [4],
    "feedText": [ "feedText" : "teszt_üzene.."]
]

println(parameters)

request(.POST, "http://localhost:7001/RestWebServiceApp/webresources/entity.bkkkallerfeedtst", parameters: parameters as! [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)
```

but i don't know how to create a json object like this:

```
{"bkkKallerFeedTst":[{"feedDate":"2015-04-08T16:27:29+02:00","feedImgType":"0","feedText":"some text","id":"1"}]}
```

When i use it, the service only get the id key.. but the feedText key not included in the response.. :(

Please help me how to solve it..

Thank you!

Comment: if i try to create my parameters this way:                                                 let parameters = [
            ["feedText": "some text"],
            ["feedImgType": "1"]      
        ]                                                                                                                       i've got this : Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array<Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>>' (0x7fb2ebfbff88) to 'Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.AnyObject>' (0x7fb2ebc75a88).

Comment: let myDictionary: [String:[String:String]] = ["bkkKallerFeedTst":["feedDate":"2015-04-08T16:27:29+02:00","feedImgType":"0","feedText":"some text","id":"1"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
let parameters = [
    "id": [4],
    "feedText": [ "feedText" : "teszt_üzene.."]
]
```

to

```
let parameters = [
        "id": [4],
        "feedText" : "teszt_üzene.."
    ]
```